# How to add a right text in BottomAppBar?

Tags: android

I have a BottomAppBar in my App, is there a way to add a TextView at the right of it?

In a fragment the Menu will be hidden and instead of it i would show the text view.

I've tried to add the TextView inside the BottomAppBar XML but it's added only at the start and if i set the width to match parent i will stop before the menu..

Here is what i've tried

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:text="articoli: 1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

While i would that text to be at the right side where the filter icon is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your TextView in a parent RelativeLayout and use  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" attribute to its child like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar"
        app:backgroundTint="#3550fe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="articoli: 1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

And the output will be like below:

[image: BottomBar_RightTextView]

And after removing the menu will be like below:

[image: BottomRightTextView_NoMenu]